# How do I index a field on a mongoose Schema that uses a discriminator?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

The error started after I started using the discriminator.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Base = require("../config/Base");

const Refill = Base.discriminator(
  "Refill",
  new Schema({
    cylinderSize: { type: Number, required: true },
    cylinderSwap: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    location: {
      type: { type: String },
      coordinates: [Number]
    }
  })
);

Refill.index({ location: "2dsphere" });


module.exports = mongoose.model("Refill");
```

This returns the error `Refill.index is not a function`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just took out the `Refill.index({ location: "2dsphere" });` and the rest of my code is working fine apparently indexing that field wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In Mongoose, indexes must be created on schemas, not models. In your case, the `Refill` object is a model. One approach is to implement this in three steps:

- Create the schema
- Add the index to the schema
- Create the model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Base = require("../config/Base");

const refillSchema =
  new Schema({
    cylinderSize: { type: Number, required: true },
    cylinderSwap: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    location: {
      type: { type: String },
      coordinates: [Number]
    }
  });

refillSchema.index({ location: "2dsphere" });

const Refill = Base.discriminator("Refill", refillSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Refill");
```